# Adding Worksheets To Current Excel Workbook

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am attempting to add a worksheet to my existing Excel instance using C#, but I get an error of

> Object not set to an instance of an object

The line that throws the code is the one that begins with `newSheet =`

I am not sure why this is being thrown as I declare my variable `newSheet` and I have instantiated `xlApp` ---- What do I need to alter in order for this syntax to work as expected?

```
public static void AddNewSheet()
{
    Excel.Application xlApp;
    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Worksheet Jobs, Estimates;
    string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\Test.xlsx";
    var xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
    Excel.Worksheet newSheet;

    //Add a new worksheet to the workbook
    newSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlApp.Worksheets.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                                            xlWorkBook.Worksheets[xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count],
                                            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                                            System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
}
```

**EDIT**
Additional Code - to hopefully assist with adding worksheets to already created workbook.

```
namespace GenerateExcelWorkbookData
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static Excel.Application xlApp;
        public static Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        public static Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        public static Excel.Worksheet newSeet;

        Main()
        {
            //Query Excel To Get DataTable Here

            //Excel Info
            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            CreateSubWorksheets();
        }
        public static void CreateSubWorksheets()
        {
            string sheetNameprefix = "SS";
            Excel.Worksheet sheet1;

            sheet1 = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Item["Newly Added"];
            Excel.Range range = sheet1.Range["A1"].CurrentRegion;
            object OriginalData = range.Value;
            string OriginalAddress = range.Address;

            while (range.Cells[2, 1].Value != null && range.Cells[2, 1].Value != "")
            {
                range.AutoFilter(1, range.Cells[2, 1].Value);

                newSeet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlApp.Worksheets.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                                                xlWorkBook.Worksheets[xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count],
                                                System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                                                System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

                //Do more stuff here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot add WorkSheet there. WorkBook is missing...

Comment: @A3006 - it works perfectly in a different C# project I run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet = null;

        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            if (xlApp == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Add();
            xlWorkSheet.Name = "Details";


 }
```

Comment: While this syntax works - it adds the new worksheet to a new workbook. I want to add the worksheets to my current workbook.

Comment: Then your reference to the WorkBook is wrong. Do you have a workbook defined in following line? xlWorkBook.Worksheets[xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count]. Here you are expecting a workbook which matches your count.

Comment: see my edit, further code provided that better illustrates.  (Code needs a complete overhaul, however for the moment I just need this element to work)